# How to launch a subprocess correctly from a blender script

Tags: python, scripting

I want to launch a command unrelated to Blender (to launch an ffmpeg job) without freezing it during the execution of the cmd (currently using os.system() ) what is the proper way of doing this ?

Comment: Question title and body mismatch - is this specific to Blenders bundled Python binary?

Comment: Example: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24172/use-array-values-from-a-c-program-in-blender/24229#24229

Answer (score 3):

Use Python's [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

This question is related and gives you some more details:

- [How to start a background process in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074)